# Calling prototype method inside function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, prototype

I am trying to *create one gallery class* using ***Javascript*** and ***jQuery***.

I have some *prototype function* for that gallery class, but when I try to access those functions inside class it shows error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Gallery.start is not a function
```

**[My JSfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/8upw9u66/1/)** 
Here is my Javascript:

```
/**
 *
 * @param options should be object of following
 * options.images Array of gallery images URL
 * options.start slide starting point
 * options.autoPlay This option will be false by default
 *
 */
function Gallery(options) {
  var _this = this;
  var galleryOptions = options;

  function randomString(len, charSet) {
    var ranString = '';
    var randomPoz;
    charSet = charSet || 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      randomPoz = Math.floor(Math.random() * charSet.length);
      ranString = ranString + charSet.substring(randomPoz, randomPoz + 1);
    }
    return ranString;
  }

  function addThumbnail(imgSrc) {
    return '<li class="thumbnail__list"><img src="' + imgSrc + '" class="thumbnail__list-img" /></li>';
  }

  function renderThumbnail(imgArr) {
    var html = [];
    if (imgArr) {
      $.each(imgArr, function(i, v) {
        html.push(addThumbnail(v));
      });
    }
    return '<ul class="gallery__thumbnail__container">' + html.join('') + '</ul>';
  }

  function getPlaceholder() {
    return 'dummy.jpg';
  }

  function disableNext(thisObj) {
    thisObj.galleryElement.find('.next').addClass('disabled');
  }

  function disablePrev(thisObj) {
    thisObj.galleryElement.find('.prev').addClass('disabled');
  }

  function enableNext(thisObj) {
    thisObj.galleryElement.find('.next').removeClass('disabled');
  }

  function enablePrev(thisObj) {
    thisObj.galleryElement.find('.prev').removeClass('disabled');
  }

  function togglePrevNext(self) {
    if (self._opt.currIndex === (self._opt.imagesLength)) {
      disableNext(self);
    } else {
      enableNext(self);
    }
    if ((self._opt.currIndex - 1) === 0) {
      disablePrev(self);
    } else {
      enablePrev(self);
    }
  }

  function controls() {
    var html = [];
    html.push('<div class="prev sz-icon-arrow-left"></div>');
    html.push('<div class="next sz-icon-arrow-right"></div>');
    return '<div class="gallery__controls">' + html.join('') + '</div>';
  }

  function bindClickEvents(galleryElement) {
    galleryElement.on('click', '.start', function() {
      _this.start();
    });
    galleryElement.find('.stop').on('click', function() {
      _this.stop();
    });
    galleryElement.find('.prev').on('click', function() {
      _this.prev();
    });
    galleryElement.find('.next').on('click', function() {
      _this.next();
    });
    galleryElement.find('.thumbnail__list').on('click', function() {
      _this.goTo(Number($(this).index()) + 1);
    });
  }

  function checkOptions(option) {
    var opt = option;
    opt.images = (opt.images.length) ? opt.images : getPlaceholder();
    opt.thumbnail = (opt.thumbnail) ? true : false;
    opt.fullScreen = (opt.fullScreen) ? true : false;
    opt.container = (opt.fullScreen) ? 'body' : opt.container;
    opt.container = (opt.container) ? opt.container : 'body';
    opt.autoPlay = (opt.autoPlay) ? true : false;
    opt.start = (opt.start && opt.start <= Number(opt.images.length)) ? opt.start : 1;
    return opt;
  }

  Gallery.init = function() {
    var html;
    _this._opt = checkOptions(galleryOptions);
    _this._opt.imagesLength = Number(_this._opt.images.length);
    _this._opt.currIndex = Number(_this._opt.start);
    _this._opt.elementName = 'gallery--' + randomString(5, 'SZgallery');
    if (_this._opt.fullScreen) {
      html = '<div class="pop-up__model ' + _this._opt.elementName + '">' +
        '<div class="pop-up__model-table">' +
        '<div class="pop-up__model-cell">' +
        '<div class="gallery"><div class="pop-up__model-content">' +
        '<div class="gallery__inner-wrapper"></div>' +
        '</div></div>' +
        '</div></div>' +
        '</div>';
      $(_this._opt.container).append('', html);
      if (_this._opt.thumbnail) {
        $('.pop-up__model-content').append('', '<div class="thumbnail__list-wrapper">' + renderThumbnail(options.images) + '</div>').append('', controls());
      }
    } else {
      $(_this._opt.container).append('', '<div class="gallery gallery--hidden ' + _this._opt.elementName + '"></div>');
    }
    _this.galleryElement = $('.' + _this._opt.elementName);
    if (_this._opt.fullScreen) {
      _this.galleryElement.find('.gallery__inner-wrapper').append('', '<div class="gallery__img-holder">' +
        '<img class="gallery__img-preview" src="' + _this._opt.images[_this._opt.start - 1] + '"/>' +
        '</div>');
    } else {
      _this.galleryElement.append('', '<div class="gallery__img-holder">' +
        '<img class="gallery__img-preview" src="' + _this._opt.images[_this._opt.start - 1] + '"/>' +
        '</div>');
    }
    if (_this._opt.thumbnail) {
      _this.galleryElement.append('', renderThumbnail(options.images)).append(controls());
    } else {
      _this.galleryElement.append('', controls());
    }

    if (_this._opt.autoPlay) {
      Gallery.start();
    }
    bindClickEvents(_this.galleryElement);
  };

  Gallery.prototype = {
    start: function() {
      _this.goTo(_this._opt.currIndex);
      _this.galleryElement.removeClass('gallery--hidden');
      console.log('started', _this._opt);
      if (_this._opt.fullScreen) {
        $('.pop-up__model').addClass('is_visible');
      }
    },
    stop: function() {
      _this.galleryElement.addClass('gallery--hidden');
    },
    next: function() {
      if (_this._opt.currIndex <= (_this._opt.imagesLength - 1)) {
        _this._opt.currIndex++;
        _this.goTo(_this._opt.currIndex);
      }
    },
    prev: function() {
      if ((_this._opt.currIndex - 1) !== 0) {
        _this._opt.currIndex--;
        _this.goTo(_this._opt.currIndex);
      }
    },
    goTo: function(imgNo) {
      var thumbnail;
      _this._opt.currIndex = Number(imgNo);
      if (_this._opt.images[imgNo - 1]) {
        _this.galleryElement.find('.gallery__img-preview').attr('src', _this._opt.images[imgNo - 1]);
      }
      if (_this._opt.thumbnail) {
        thumbnail = _this.galleryElement.find('.thumbnail__list');
        thumbnail.removeClass('active');
        thumbnail.eq(imgNo - 1).addClass('active');
      }
      togglePrevNext(_this);
    },
    destroy: function() {
      console.log('destroyed');
    }
  };

  return Gallery;
}

var imgArr = ['images/placeholder-1.png', 'images/placeholder-2.png', 'images/placeholder-3.jpg', 'images/placeholder-4.jpg'];


var hotelPhotosGallery = new Gallery({
  images: imgArr,
  autoPlay: true,
  container: '.photo-list'
});
hotelPhotosGallery.init();
```

Answer (score 2):

After looking a bit at your code, I found the problem:

```
if (_this._opt.autoPlay) {
  Gallery.start(); // This method doesn't exist on a non instantiated object
}
```

**You are trying to call a method on the function itself**, not a method on the prototype of an instance of that function (instantiated using `new`).

However, **prototype methods won't be available on non-instantiated items** because `this` in a function gets attached to the global object by default. When using `new`, that `this` actually becomes a new object and gets implicitly returned from the `function`, thus creating a new instance. [More about using function constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function)

Generally, this would be fixed by using the context (i.e. `this`) instead of the function name:

```
if (_this._opt.autoPlay) {
  this.start(); // Use the context of the instantiated Gallery
}
```

In your particular case however, you are **re-defining** the prototype:

```
Gallery.prototype = { ... } // You are overwriting the prototype object
```

Instead of using the one that the JS engine already prepared for you and add methods on it:

```
// add methods directly on the prototype
Gallery.prototype.method1 = // ...
Gallery.prototype.method2 = // ...
```

This way is [**potentially unsafe**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256535/is-it-ok-to-assign-the-javascript-prototype-object-instead-of-just-its-propertie) since it will end up removing anything else that existed in the prototype before you re-defined it.

If you are not concerned with this and would like to keep your code the way it is, you can access your method also by **explicitly** calling the prototype:

```
if (_this._opt.autoPlay) {
  Gallery.prototype.start(); // Explicitly call the prototype, since you already defined it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not calling it properly. if you need to call prototype function it must be like

> Gallery.prototype.start()

if you are trying to implement a special behavior (object based) then it should be like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560829/calling-base-method-using-javascript-prototype?answertab=active#tab-top). also here are some different ways of simulating the class in [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662147/how-to-access-object-prototype-in-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top)